# Whats the easiest way to get an add on working again?

Tags: add-on

I have been using the rock generator function which is part of the Add Mesh: Extra Objects add on in Blender 2.9.

I found a section of the code wasn't working the way I wanted it to and hence edited one of the python scripts associated with the rock generation.

I now realize that this was a mistake. The option to add rocks has disappeared from blender (although the Add Mesh: Extra Objects add on is selected).

I have also changed back the add on and have found another way (in my own blender scripting) to get round the issue I was having with the add-on.

Whats the easiest way to get the rock generator add on working again?

Comment: Have you tried simply reinstalling it? All of the bundled addons come with any build of blender...

Comment: @Timaroberts I have now, and have everything back, however im still curious about whether theres another way of doing it.